# (HTML5) music player with $_POST/no direct links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Does anyone know a way to realize a HTML5  player without page reload and via $_POST?
Or perhaps a free music player where the direct links to the music files do not appear in the source text?

Why? I want a music player where the visitors don't have the possibility to call or download the songs directly.

Comment: A URL points to the resource (audio file). The browser (media player within) must access that resource via that URL. Therefore, the URL is always available within the browser (via player menus or developer console). You cannot achieve your goal.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't found a solution. Only thousands who have the same request.
Now I "secured" it with .htaccess using a referer. Is not really a protection that someone downloads the files, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that is personally satisfactory for me. Playing MP3 works, but JDownloader can't download it. A cookie is set on the main page and the music is only processed if this cookie is present.

.htaccess Music folder

```
<Files "*.*">
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

The call of the music file takes place via $_GET and is processed via PHP.

```
define('MusicFolder',   '/music/');

$track = isset($_GET['track']) && $_GET['track']!='' ? $_GET['track']:'';

if($track) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['NH'])) {
        $file   = ReleasesMusicFolder.basename($track);

        if(file_exists($file)) {
            $size   = filesize($file);
            $mime   = mime_content_type($file);
            header("Content-type: ".$mime."");
            header("Content-length: ".$size."");
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
            readfile($file);
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        die('Access denied');
    }
}
```